SetVariable showing empty array
I Have problem in react, I use fetch API from tutorial to get data from my API to show data on react Here is my JSON:
{
  "Konfigurasi": [
    {
      "id_konfigurasi": 1,
      "bahasa": "ID",
      "namaweb": "Universitas",
      "tagline": "home 2",
      "singkatan": "UBG",
      "id_user": 16,
      "periode_satu": "11 Desember 2023 s.d 30 April 2024 (Sudah Tutup)",
      "periode_dua": "1 Mei 2024 s.d 31 Juli 2024 (Sedang Dibuka)",
      "periode_tiga": "Belum Dibuka",
      "tanggal": "2023-05-10T02:44:44.000Z"
    }
  ]
}

And here my code:
const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState([]);

async function getConfiguration(){  
  const postData = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  }

  fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL+'/api/Configuration',postData)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setConfiguration(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

useEffect(()=>{
  getConfiguration()
},[])

The code was working, I try to console log the data it shows API array but when I try to send it to configuration, its show nothing, just empty array. It's probably me missing something.
I try few tutorial and its not working, I want to put the JSON data into the Configuration variable, Is it from my code or i miss something?
I am sorry I'm not very good at English.

Does this answer your question? React setState not updating state

It works, but its send back 900 API calls when i console log it.

You should include the surrounding component code so we can see what you're trying to do with the data once you've retrieved it. You shouldn't be posting 900 API calls as you're only calling that effect once when the component renders so a little more context will be useful.

yah that's actually my problem, after i try everything i found out the problem with the answr bryan send i didn't put my second argument on useState, so its keep sending API indenfinetly. Thanks for help tho, you all help me out.

Okay so after many testing its seems like the problem is with my file, i fix it with making a new project file and send everything there. after that file still empty and after trying mess up with every code, i found out i cant console.log the useState. It only can read mapping. so everything fix now Thanks for everyone helping.

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState([]);

async function getConfiguration() {
    try {
        const response = await ``fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/Configuration`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        setConfiguration(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch configuration:', error);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getConfiguration();
}, []);


Data still send nothing i try to map it but it didn't show anything, Thanks tho

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
